# How to contribute to the documentation?

Tags: documentation

How do I contribute to the CiviCRM documentation?

I'd like to contribute to the Set-up page of the CiviMail documentation. There are some things that tripped me and I'd like to share them with others now that I figured them out.

Note: I tried clicking the link on the line "CiviCRM documentation is community driven. You can help improve documentation." (found at the bottom of the documentation pages), however it leads to a 404.

UPDATE:
Here is the page which I wanted to edit: http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/email/setup/

Comment: Can you add the link you were trying to edit to your question?

Comment: @Laryn I added the link to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're in a bit of a transition phase at the moment with the tools we use for writing documentation.

The authoritative user and admin guide is here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide.

1. fork the repository (you'll need a github account to do that)
2. make the edit directly on your fork of the repository
3. submit a pull request back to the original repository with a summary of your edit, why you made it, etc.

If it is a small edit, then the above is all you need to do. If it is a larger edit (or if you just feel like it) then you probably want to submit a documentation ticket on jira to discuss what you are planning on doing https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa

If you think that you'll be making a few edits, then here's a bit more reading that you might find useful.

- https://civicrm.org/blogs/michael-mcandrew/moving-civicrms-user-and-administrator-guide-gitbook-or-readthedocs
- https://civicrm.org/improve-documentation

Answer (score 3):

"The CiviCRM User and Administrator Book - version 4.6" is at http://gitbook.civicrm.org/

To contribute see: http://gitbook.civicrm.org/the-civicrm-community/contributing-to-this-manual.html